# Add Firebase auth and database but auth undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm using next.js and Firebase. This is may be a simple problem, but I didn't find any solution.

this is my code :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";

import CONFIG from "../../config";

const prodConfig = CONFIG.FIREBASE.PROD;

const devConfig = CONFIG.FIREBASE.DEV;

const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? prodConfig : devConfig;

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    console.log(config);
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

console.log(firebase);
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.database();


export { db, auth };
```

I already import `firebase/auth` and `firebase/database`. On the console, database is exist, but `auth` undefined.

I am using `"firebase": "^6.0.2",`

Why my Firebase auth is undefined?

Error :

`firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.auth is not a function`